# How to become a rated player?

Tags: rating, fide

Can someone explain to me what are the procedures involvd in getting a chess rating? If different countries have different procedures then how one can get an international chess rating in India?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to play against players who already have a FIDE rating in competitions which are themselves FIDE rated. The numbers keep changing but I think you need at least one draw out of 5 games against FIDE rated opposition. This doesn't have to be achieved in one competition but there is a time limit before your games expire, something like 2 years, but I don't know exactly.

I should add that FIDE have standard, rapid and blitz ratings and these don't mix. So, if you play 3 FIDE rated opponents in a standard time control competition and 2 in rapid or blitz that does not count as 5.

EDIT:
I've checked out what the [FIDE site says](https://www.fide.com/fide/handbook.html?id=172&view=article):

> 6.1 If an unrated player scores zero in his first tournament, his score and that of his opponents against him are disregarded. 
>   Otherwise, if an unrated player has played rated games, then this
>   result is included in computing his overall rating.
>
> 6.31 For an unrated player’s first performance to count, he must score at least 1/2 point.
>
> 7.14 A rating for a player new to the list shall be published only if it meets the following criteria:
>
> 7.14a If based on results obtained under 6.2 [round robin with min 4 rated players], a minimum of 5 games.
>
> 7.14b If based on results obtained under 6.3 [swiss], a minimum of 5 games played against rated opponents.
>
> 7.14c The condition of a minimum of 5 games need not be met in one tournament. Results from other tournaments played within consecutive
>   rating periods totalling not more than 26 months, are pooled to obtain
>   the initial rating.

7.14d
The rating is at least 1000.

7.14e
The rating is calculated using all his results as if they were played in one tournament (it is not published until he has played at least 5 games) by using all the rating data available.